# Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a skew-symmetric matrix, is the Rayleigh quotient of $A$ always $0$?

Tags: matrices, sturm-liouville, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a skew-symmetric matrix, is the Rayleigh quotient of $A$ always $0$?

The Rayleigh quotient is define as following:
$$\mathcal{W}_{\mathbb{R}}(A)=\big\{ \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} \big \}$$

Comment: Rayleigh quotient is usually defined as the ratio $\frac{x^\ast Ax}{x^\ast x}$ for some specific $x\ne0$, not the *set* of all such ratios.

Comment: Take $x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T=-x^TAx$ so yes here